# Overload string method

Tags: python

I want to overload my string method, s.t. I get the following output:

```
print Class_name({6:7, 4:5, 7:7}) 
7*x^7 + 7*x^6 + 5*x^4
```

I did the following:

```
def __str__(self):
    self.poly = []
    for k,v in sorted(self.dictionary.iteritems()):
        if k == 0:
            self.poly.append(str(v))
        elif v == 1:
            self.poly.append('*x^'+str(k))
        else:
            self.poly.append(str(v)+'*x^'+str(k))
    out = ""
    for el in self.poly:
        out += str(el) + " + "
    self.out = out[:-2]
    return self.out
```

Why does this not work? 
Entering 
`print Class_name({6:7, 4:5, 7:7})` , I get

```
{4: 13, 6: 14, 7: 7}
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
If I've an additional def:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    out = self.dictionary
    for k,v in sorted(other.dictionary.iteritems(), reverse=True):
        try:
            out[k] += v
        except:
            out[k] = v

    return out
```

and I want to do this:

```
print Class_name({6:7, 4:5, 7:7})+Class_name({6:7, 4:5, 7:7})
```

I get:
`{6:14, 4:10, 7:14}` instead of the desired representation.

Comment: Where exactly are you defining `__str__()`?

Comment: It looks like a programming assignment ...

Comment: what on earth are you trying to achieve this way... no better way, really?

Comment: Please also provide you `__init__` function.

Comment: You completely changed the question.  It would have been more appropriated to ask a new question for addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the addition to work:

```
def __add__(self, other):

    #...

    return Class_name(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (cut and paste from your code, wrapped in a class definition)

```
class cn:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.dictionary = d

    def __str__(self):
        self.poly = []
        for k,v in sorted(self.dictionary.iteritems()):
            if k == 0:
                self.poly.append(str(v))
            elif v == 1:
                self.poly.append('*x^'+str(k))
            else:
                self.poly.append(str(v)+'*x^'+str(k))
        out = ""
        for el in self.poly:
            out += str(el) + " + "
        self.out = out[:-2]
        return self.out


print cn({"1":"2"})


~ mgregory$ python foo.py
2*x^1 
~ mgregory$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
~ mgregory$
```

I wonder whether you didn't actually define the `__str__()` of your class - maybe you just defined a function called `__str__()`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `__repr__` function for the class

```
class Poly():
    def __init__(self, coeffs):
        values = [(factor, power) for power, factor in coeffs.items()]
        self.poly = sorted(values, reverse = True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return ' + '.join('{}*x^{}'.format(f, p) for f, p in self.poly)
```

Example

```
>>> a = Poly({6:7, 4:5, 7:7})

>>> a
7*x^7 + 7*x^6 + 5*x^4

>>> print(a)
7*x^7 + 7*x^6 + 5*x^4

>>> str(a)
'7*x^7 + 7*x^6 + 5*x^4'
```

Comment: Maybe he does, for some purposes, but print calls `__str__()`, doesn't it?

Comment: @GreenAsJade See my edit, all of those examples work properly with the class I defined in the example.